# Is there a way to loop my program when it finishes? I always get an infinite loop

Tags: java, loops

I made a wages program and I need to loop it so it runs for multiple employees.

Right now, it works fine for one person, but if I stick a `while(true){` at the top of the program, it infinite loops and prints messages forever. I am rather new to Java so any suggestions are appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Wages {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
        int inTime = 0;
        int outTime = 0;
        int inMin = 0;//convert time to minutes for easier calculation
        int outMin = 0;
        int iLength = 0;
        double minWorked = 0;
        double hoursWorked = 0;
        double totalPay = 0;
        double PPH = 0; //pay per hour
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = "";
        String timeIn = "";

        while (true) {
            while (iLength < 3) { //loop if input is invalid
                System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
                name = sc.nextLine();
                name = name.trim(); //trim spaces
                iLength = name.length();//check length
                if (iLength < 3) {//error message
                    System.out.println("Please enter a name longer than 3 characters.");
                }
            }
            try {
                while ((inTime < 800 || outTime > 1900) || outTime <= inTime) {
                    System.out.print("Please enter your check in time: ");
                    inTime = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Please enter your check out time: ");
                    outTime = sc.nextInt();
                    if (inTime < 800 || outTime > 1900) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter work time between 800 and 1900.");
                    }
                    if (outTime <= inTime) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a check out time later than your check in time.");
                    }
                }
                while (PPH < 7.75 || PPH > 15.20) {
                    System.out.print("Please enter your pay per hour: $");
                    PPH = sc.nextDouble();
                    if (PPH < 7.75 || PPH > 15.20) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a pay between 7.75 and 15.20.");
                    }
                }
                inMin = (inTime / 100) * 60 + (inTime % 100);
                outMin = (outTime / 100) * 60 + (outTime % 100);
                minWorked = outMin - inMin;
                hoursWorked = minWorked / 60;
                totalPay = hoursWorked * PPH;
                System.out.println("\nEmployee Name: " + name);
                System.out.println("Check in time: " + inTime);
                System.out.println("Check out time: " + outTime);
                System.out.println("Hours worked: " + hoursWorked);
                System.out.println("Pay per hour: " + money.format(PPH));
                System.out.println("Total pay: " + money.format(totalPay));
            }//try
            catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("Please enter time and pay as numbers.");
            }
        }//while(true)
    }//main
}//class
```

Comment: What condition do you want to loop on? `while(true)` will never end until the program does or it encounters a `break;`.

Comment: You are missing the issue. The issue isn't the infinite loop, but the fact that it never asks for input again due to the input variables not being reset. See my answer below.

Comment: Yes, Zwander is correct that it was not resetting my variables. I fixed it with his answer thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are never resetting your input variables. Thus when the loop gets back to the start, the variables are already set and the program skips through your validation checks.

For example at the start of the loop we set `iLength` and `name`. Say `name="Alex"` and thus `iLength=4`. This passes the `while(iLength<3)` check. Then the rest of the data is entered (lets pretend) and the loop is completed. We then get back to the piece of code `while(iLength<3)`. Because we havent reset `iLength`, `iLength` is still 4, and thus it never even asks for a name.

You either need to declare your variables in the `while(true)` loop, thus meaning they are destroyed and recreated each loop, or you need to reset them at the end of each loop. e.g:
`iLength=0;
 name="";`

It is also notable that you should have a way to break the infinite loop. EG:

`if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) return;`

This will end the program if the name "exit" is entered (with any case variation).

Comment: Awesome! Tick the tick then to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `for(;;) {}` to create an infinite loop then just `break` based on a condition (number of runs/user input/etc).

Comment: It is generally considered better practice to use `while(true)` instead of `for(;;)`.

Comment: Yes, but it is always better to know that both methods exist.

Comment: Why? There is literally no difference between the effects, one is simply better practice than the other. It also just doesn't seem to work in my head if I imagine breaking out of an infinite loop with `break;` instead of a condition as part of the loop declaration.

Comment: Why know both? Because it is likely that one will run into an infinite for loop because some co-worker or professor prefers it. In his case, I would use the methods that others have suggested which use a Boolean flag variable to create a conditional loop.

Comment: Or you can use stream() if you're using Java 8. That pretty much outperforms all the above in simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many employees then use a for loop instead.

If you don't know how many employees then you need to ask the user when to quit and use that answer in your while loop, for example:

```
boolean goAgain = true;
while(goAgain){
    //do your employee stuff
    //ask user if they want to go again
    goAgain = false; //assuming the user is finished
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a combination of all the answers previously. Might need some edge case testing but resetting the variable restarts wages from the beginning. The do while is just my preference.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Wages{

public static void main (String[ ] arg){
  DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
  int inTime = 0;
  int outTime = 0;
  int inMin = 0;//convert time to minutes for easier calculation
  int outMin = 0;
  int iLength = 0;
  double minWorked = 0;
  double hoursWorked = 0;
  double totalPay = 0;
  double PPH = 0; //pay per hour
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String name = "";
  String timeIn = "";
  boolean again = true;
do{
      while(iLength<3){ //loop if input is invalid
         System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
         name = sc.nextLine( );
         name = name.trim( ); //trim spaces
         iLength = name.length( );//check length
         if(iLength<3){//error message
            System.out.println("Please enter a name longer than 3 characters.");
         }
      }
      try{
             while((inTime<800 || outTime>1900)||outTime<=inTime){
                System.out.print("Please enter your check in time: ");
                inTime = sc.nextInt( );
                System.out.print("Please enter your check out time: ");
                outTime = sc.nextInt( );
                if(inTime<800||outTime>1900){
                   System.out.println("Please enter work time between 800 and 1900.");
                }
                if(outTime<=inTime){
                   System.out.println("Please enter a check out time later than your check in time.");
                }
             }   
             while(PPH<7.75||PPH>15.20){
                System.out.print("Please enter your pay per hour: $");
                PPH = sc.nextDouble( );
                if(PPH<7.75||PPH>15.20){
                   System.out.println("Please enter a pay between 7.75 and 15.20.");
                }               
                 }
             inMin = (inTime/100)*60 + (inTime%100);
             outMin = (outTime/100)*60 + (outTime%100);
             minWorked = outMin - inMin;
             hoursWorked = minWorked/60;
             totalPay = hoursWorked*PPH;  
             System.out.println("\nEmployee Name: " + name);
             System.out.println("Check in time: " + inTime);
             System.out.println("Check out time: " +outTime);
             System.out.println("Hours worked: " + hoursWorked);
             System.out.println("Pay per hour: " +money.format(PPH));   
             System.out.println("Total pay: " + money.format(totalPay));  
             System.out.println("Do you want to enter another employee? (Y/N)");
             if (sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("n")){//left the exception handling up to you 
                 again = false;  
             }
             iLength =0;
             inTime = 0;
             outTime= 0;
             PPH = 0;
        }
      catch(InputMismatchException ime){
         System.out.println("Please enter time and pay as numbers.");
        }
    }while(again);
}
```